# Jquery animation after complete page loaded

Tags: jquery

How to do an animation after a page(images and everything) completely loaded with Jquery.( like please wait screen before a page is loading)

Thank You

Update:

I need to hide everything in the page and once everything loaded then only the page has to be show.

Comment: dont know ..... i suppose like gmail you mean

Answer (score 7):

```
$(window).load(function(){
  $('#loading').fadeOut('fast');
});
```

fadeOut() can be changed to antything you want.

Answer (score 0):

Isn't that what the `$(document).ready(function(){ /*something*/ });` is all about?

Comment: nope ... how would you know that the content of page has been loaded

Answer (score 0):

if you want to preload images. refer http://ditio.net/2010/02/14/jquery-preload-images-tutorial-and-example/